# Terraform GCP startup script local file instead of inline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, startup

Lots of examples exist online that show how to run a startup script on a VM deployed on GCP/GCE with Terraform, but they all use inline startup scripts, with all the startup script code included in the terraform compute.tf file. This is done either with a single line for the startup script, or with <<SCRIPT[script code]SCRIPT for multiple lines. I haven't found a single example showing a way to assign the startup script parameter to another file on local disk, perhaps in the same directory as compute.tf. It is quite a mess to clutter compute.tf with hundreds of lines of startup script. Isn't there a better way to do this?

I realize I could write a wrapper script that combines a compute.tf and a separate startup file into a single compute.tf and then runs terraform, but I'm seeking a more direct route, assuming one exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To reference a file in your GCE VM declarations just use the [file function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#file-path-) to read the contents from your selected file. For example:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  …
  metadata_startup_script = "${file("/path/to/your/file")}"
}
```

On a similar note, you can also use the [template_file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) data source to perform token replacement on a template file and then reference the resolved file content in your GCE VM declaration. For example:

```
data “template_file” “default” {
  template = “${file(“/path/to/your/file”)}”
  vars = {
    address = “some value“
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  …
  metadata_startup_script = "${data.template_file.default.rendered}"
}
```

References:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#file-path-
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html

Comment: How can you see the output of the `metadata_startup_script` when this is executed?    Currently the script is executed with this syntax but I do not see any script output / errors

Comment: Regardless of how the startup script is supplied (whether in-line or using the file function) the script is executed _on_ the GCE VM so you'll see its output in [serial port output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) or by checking its logs in Stackdriver or by accessing the VM and reading the logs [directly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript).

Answer (score 5):

Re-run custom startup scripts by logging into the instance and running.

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

And also to enable full debugging, do this

```
sudo DEBUG=1 google_metadata_script_runner
```

Comment: Debug works with "--debug" at the end:
sudo DEBUG=1 google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup --debug